# merging table rows html

Tags: java, html, jsp

I created a html table using a for loop which creates the table dynamically in a jsp.

Below is the piece of code.

Java for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<mleFIPStepsInfo.size(); i++)
{
    Map map = (Map) mleFIPStepsInfo.get(i);
```

html code:

```
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;" rowspan=4><span style="font-size:13px;"><strong><span style="font-family:calibri;"><%=map.get("attribute[Sequence]")%>&nbsp;</td>

        <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:13px;"><strong><span style="font-family:calibri;"><%=map.get("name")%>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:13px;"><strong><span style="font-family:calibri;"><%=map.get("description")%>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:13px;"><strong><span style="font-family:calibri;"><%=map.get("attribute[Instructions]")%>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

Now i have 10 records.

For first 5 records sequence number is 1 and others are 2,3,4,5,6. Now i am trying to build a with 10 rows and i should have first 5 rows to be merged like below:

Sequence    Name    Description     Instructions

```
        Name1   Description1    Instructions1
        Name2   Description2    Instructions2
```

1           Name3   Description3    Instructions3

```
        Name4   Description4    Instructions4
        Name5   Description5    Instructions5
```

2           Name6   Description6    Instructions6

3           Name7   Description7    Instructions7

4           Name8   Description8    Instructions8

5           Name9   Description9    Instructions9

6           Name10  Description10   Instructions10

I can't able to print the table properly here in StackOverflow but what i basically need is in the first 5 rows needs to be merged with sequence number 1.

Comment: Unclear what you want it to finally look like.  Do you want the first 5 rows to be shown as one row?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. What i basically need is first 5 rows to be merged for column 1 which is Sequence. I know if i keep rowspan="5" and colspan="1" which will make the the first 5 rows merged but i am unable to generate the logic for the same in the loop.

Comment: Something like: <tr><td>Sequence 1</td><td>Name 1<br>Name 2<br>Name 3<br>...</td></tr>?

Answer (score 0):

You want the first 5 rows to appear as one very long row, you need to omit the close  for each row whose next row has the same sequence number and the open  for each row whose proceeding row has the same sequence number.

Something like:

```
for(Map.Entry entry : map) {
   if(prevEntry != null && prevEntry.sequence != entry.sequence) {
      write("<tr>");
   }
   // Write the rest of the row here
   if(nextEntry != null && nextEntry.sequence != entry.sequence) {
      write("</tr>");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. But i need it in a different way. Let us assume if a table has 4 columns. Column headings are "Step sequence", "Name", "Description", "Instructions". If table has 10 rows and sequence number "1" is same for the first 5 rows, in this case i need to merge 5 rows for only column 1 which is Step sequence and the other other data remains same. Basically first column has 6 rows and the other 3 columns has 10 rows. I am not sure whether i am conveying correctly. Is there any way i can draw a table here and show you?? Thanks....

Comment: Can you elaborate on the different way you need?